# How to use code to control the printer paper scaling

Tags: c#, winforms

use winforms.

The report is designed on A4 paper, but the customer requires A5 paper to be printed.

Only this report needs to be scaled, and other documents do not need to be scaled when printing, so I want to set the scaling before printing this report, and then restore it after printing.
[image]

new screenshot
[image]

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing how you are generating your report today. By printing directly using the Graphics class or some report generator (which then)?

Comment: The Settings on the picture are the print preferences in the printer Settings

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you trying to write a program to scale a page (most printers will do this for you). Or are you trying to automate applying settings to a print job? Or something else? We will need more information to be able to answer your question.

Comment: Put it this way
I just want to control the scaling in printing preferences using C# code
It doesn’t matter which reporting tool is used